# 'str' object has no attribute 'id' django

Tags: django

Am trying to add a package on my django app. I finished all the installation process but ma getting this error which i don't know. I tried entering into the file and modify but i was not luck. here is the error. Am using my own custom user model that's why i am importing accounts.model:

```
 AttributeError at /s/about/
'str' object has no attribute 'id'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/s/about/
Django Version: 2.2.17
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'str' object has no attribute 'id'
Exception Location: /home/Comfort_Chambeshi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djangorave/templatetags/djangorave_tags.py in pay_button_params, line 32
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/media/Comfort_Chambeshi/Reserved/projects/web/ludocs_emark',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/Comfort_Chambeshi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 21 Nov 2020 22:40:43 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template /home/Comfort_Chambeshi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djangorave/templates/djangorave/pay_button.html, error at line 13

'str' object has no attribute 'id'
3   <!--
4       User email is required by Rave, therefore user must be signed in before
5       button will be displayed.
6   -->
7   <script>
8       function createPaymentParams() {
9           //
10          // Create payment params which will be sent to Rave upon payment
11          //
12          {% autoescape off %}
13          let pay_button_params = JSON.parse('{% if user.is_authenticated %}{% pay_button_params user=user payment_type=payment_type %}{% endif %}');
14          {% endautoescape %}
15          paymentParams['{{ payment_type.description }}'] = {
16              PBFPubKey: pay_button_params.pub_key,
17              amount: '{{ payment_type.amount }}',
18              currency: '{{ payment_type.currency }}',
19              custom_logo: '{{ payment_type.custom_logo }}',
20              custom_title: '{{ payment_type.custom_title }}',
21              customer_email: '{{ user.email }}',
22              customer_firstname: '{{ user.first_name }}',
23              customer_lastname: '{{ user.last_name }}',
```

djangorave_tags.py:

```
# stdlib imports
import json

# django imports
from accounts.models import User
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django import template

# 3rd party imports

# project imports
from djangorave.models import PaymentTypeModel
from djangorave import settings
from djangorave.utils import create_integrity_hash


register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag()
def pay_button_params(user: User, payment_type: PaymentTypeModel) -> str:
    """Returns params required when submitting a payment request to rave.

    Returns:
        txref: created by combining payment_type.id, timestamp and user_id
        redirect_url: transaction detail page to redirect to
        pub_key: PBFPubKey from settings
        integrity_hash: used by rave to ensure client side values are note altered
    """
    now = timezone.now().timestamp()
    txref = f"{payment_type.id}__{now}__{user.id}"
    redirect_url = reverse("djangorave:reference", kwargs={"reference": txref})
    integrity_hash = create_integrity_hash(
        payment_type=payment_type, user=user, txref=txref, redirect_url=redirect_url
    )
    return json.dumps(
        {
            "txref": txref,
            "redirect_url": redirect_url,
            "pub_key": settings.PUBLIC_KEY,
            "integrity_hash": integrity_hash,
        }
    )


@register.simple_tag()
def rave_inline_js() -> str:
    """Return the RAVE_INLINE_JS setting"""
    return settings.RAVE_INLINE_JS
```